# Adding style for asp.net drop-down list control using bootstrap v3

Tags: asp.net, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was trying to add style for asp.net drop-down list control using bootstrap 3. But it is not applying. Earlier it worked with bootstrap 2.3.2 without any changes.

Can anybody suggest me a way to do this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would say this would be enough:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="something" />
```

Take a look at [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) and scroll down to the **Selects** section.

Comment: this answer is also valid for bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1):

You can use this and change btn whatever you want:
`<asp:DropDownList Width="100%" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-sm" ID="DPCID" runat="server"/>`