# Styling Asp:Dropdownlist and Asp:ListItem using Bootstrap?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

just a quick question, How do you style an Asp:Dropdownlist and its ListItem using bootstrap?

Does it have to do with CssClass?
From what the system says CssClass is not a valid attribute in the element ListItem.
Can you add Span Class inside the text?

Here's a sample code:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="dropdownrole" data-style="btn-primary" CssClass="dropdown-menu">
                    <asp:ListItem CssClass="btn-primary" Text="-- Select a user to proceed --"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Admin"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Student" ></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Teacher"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541615/adding-style-for-asp-net-drop-down-list-control-using-bootstrap-v3)?

For me it was enough to add CssClass="form-control"

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="dropdown-menu form-control" runat="server" id="dropdownrole" data-style="btn-primary">
```

Comment: I've Tried it. It does not affect the styling with the ListItem, I don't know why.

Comment: Welcome to asp world :)

Comment: Try overriding css class for select.item, because asp adds it's own styling. The only thing is to specify your own style

Comment: Or use html select. Believe me, it'll be the easiest solution

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for that:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  id="dropdownrole" >
                    <asp:ListItem Text="-- Select a user to proceed --"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Admin"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Student" ></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Teacher"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

I think you can't change the selects style with bootstrap, please read the selects section [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls). (scroll down)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:ListItem>Allahabad</asp:ListItem>

  <asp:ListItem>Kanpur</asp:ListItem>

  <asp:ListItem>Rewa</asp:ListItem>

  <asp:ListItem>Bhopal</asp:ListItem>

  <asp:ListItem>Indore</asp:ListItem>

  <asp:ListItem>Jabalpur</asp:ListItem>
```

Refer this:

http://www.mindstick.com/Blog/639/Dropdownlist%20using%20BootStrap%20in%20ASP%20Net#.VgUYlVanJ7Y