# How to get bootstrap dropdown list style on asp:DropDownList without using form-control class

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to add bootstrap style to an old application.  One thing I have come across repeatedly is wanting to style an asp:DropDownList as a bootstrap [dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/).

I came across a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541615/adding-style-for-asp-net-drop-down-list-control-using-bootstrap-v3) that said to use the form-control class.  This actually works *however* it gives the control a width of 100% thanks to the form-control class which is taking priority over the grid's width.

I have been trying to figure out how to get it to prioritize the grid width, however I wonder that applying form-control is the wrong solution in the first place.

I would definitely prefer not to rewrite the asp:DropDownList using a button and ul as done in bootstrap examples b/c I would have to repeat this transformation a hundred  times and it's simply not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, you could add a width to the dropdownlist like this:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName"
            width="180px"
            ></asp:DropDownList>
```